# Adding the word "Appendix" for all the Appendices chapters using the quotchap package

Tags: quotchap

I am using the quotchap package and for all the Appendices, I want to add the word "Appendix" before the appendix number e.g. Appendix A instead of A. My problem is shown in the picture below
[image: My problem]
I need assistance on how to obtain the following output:
[image: My desired output]
Below is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,openany,twoside]{book}
\raggedbottom
\let\cleardoublepage=\clearpage
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\HRule{\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1.5pt}}
\usepackage[dotinlabels]{titletoc}
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{contents={}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hhline}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\usepackage[noindentafter,calcwidth]{titlesec}
\usepackage[courier]{quotchap}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand\sectfont{\bfseries}
\usepackage{calc,pifont} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcommand*\myheaderfooterfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[ragged]{sidecap}
\usepackage[marginal]{footmisc}
\renewcommand\footnoterule{\vspace*{-3pt}%
    \hrule width 2in height 1.4pt \vspace*{2.6pt}}
\setlength\footnotemargin{10pt}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
}
\usepackage[toc,header]{appendix}
\usepackage{apptools}
\begin{document} 
        \frontmatter
\chapter*{Ac}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Ac}

\mainmatter
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\chapter{Backrre}

\begin{appendices}
    \renewcommand{\chaptername}{Appendix}
    \chapter{Derivation of X}
    The contents...
    \chapter{Derivation of Y}
    Another content...
\end{appendices}

\backmatter

\bibliography{}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `quotechap` package does not use the `\chaptername` in its definition of `\chapter`. You need to revise some of the `quotechap` chapter related macros in your preamble.

Comment: @Peter Wilson, can you please assist. I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code modifies the `\@makechapterhead` macro of the `quotchap` package to add the word Appendix to appendices (A to D).

[image: a]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[11pt,openany,twoside]{book}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% added <<<<<<
\raggedbottom
\let\cleardoublepage=\clearpage
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\HRule{\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1.5pt}}
\usepackage[dotinlabels]{titletoc}
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{contents={}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hhline}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\usepackage[noindentafter,calcwidth]{titlesec}
\usepackage[courier]{quotchap}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand\sectfont{\bfseries}
\usepackage{calc,pifont} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcommand*\myheaderfooterfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[ragged]{sidecap}
\usepackage[marginal]{footmisc}
\renewcommand\footnoterule{\vspace*{-3pt}%
    \hrule width 2in height 1.4pt \vspace*{2.6pt}}
\setlength\footnotemargin{10pt}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
}
\usepackage[toc,header]{appendix}
\usepackage{apptools}   

\usepackage{showframe}

%************************************************** added
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand{\appname}{{\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{22pt}{26pt}\selectfont\raisebox{1em}{\textcolor{red}{Appendix}}}} % set the appendix name <<<<<<<<<<<  
\makeatletter   
    \patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\thechapter}{%
     \IfSubStr{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}{\thechapter}{\appname\,\thechapter}{\thechapter}
    }           
\makeatother    
%************************************************** 

\begin{document} 
    \frontmatter
    \chapter*{Ac}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Ac}
    
    \mainmatter
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
    \chapter{Backrre}
    
    \begin{appendices}
        \chapter{Derivation of X}
        The contents...
        \chapter{Derivation of Y}
        Another content...
        \setcounter{chapter}{15}
        \chapter{Derivation of P}
        \setcounter{chapter}{25}
        \chapter{Derivation of Z}
        Another content...      
    \end{appendices}
    
    \backmatter     
%   \bibliography{}
    
\end{document
```

**UPDATE** after follow up question.

[image: z]

Comment: What if I have I have Appendices from A-M? Is there a way of automating the code such that whenever the Chapters are in letters of the alphabet, i.e Appendix A, B, C,... then we automatically have Appendix G, H,... for example?

Comment: @itc Of course. If all else meets your requirements, I'll add the full alphabet as an update.

Comment: you can edit the code so that it automatically deals with the issue I have mentioned in my comment above.

Comment: @itc Done! Please check the new code. Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: Thank you very much @Simon Dispa, the code is now working perfectly. And just out of curiosity, lets say I want to do the same for the main chapters, what changes should I make to the solution you posted above?

Comment: @itc I think it can be done, but please ask a new question (it will help other readers) and keep me posted.

Comment: Noted with thanks.