# Alignment of all chapters and appendices labels and numbers to the right margin using quotchap package

Tags: quotchap, sidebearings

**Problem Description**

I am having a problem with the right alignment of chapters and appendices labels and numbers to the right margin. In the picture below (just an example and a representation of the problem I am facing), it can be seen that the chapter name (**Backrre**) is properly aligned to the right margin (indicated by the black vertical line). However, the chapter label and number (**Chapter 1**) is not aligned to the right margin as can be seen by the space/gap between the blue line (the blue vertical line I added to illustrate my problem) and the right margin (shown by the black vertical line) in the picture below.
[image: Problem description]
I need assistance on how to align the chapters labels and numbers to the right margin as are the chapter names. Below is my MWE which was a solution to my previous problem that @Simon Dispa (https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/161015/simon-dispa) assisted me with at [Adding the word "Chapter" before Chapter number using the quotchap package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/650307/adding-the-word-chapter-before-chapter-number-using-the-quotchap-package/650342?noredirect=1#comment1620861_650342):

```
\documentclass[11pt,openany,twoside]{book}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% added <<<<<<
\raggedbottom
\let\cleardoublepage=\clearpage
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\HRule{\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1.5pt}}
\usepackage[dotinlabels]{titletoc}
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{contents={}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hhline}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\usepackage[noindentafter,calcwidth]{titlesec}
\usepackage[courier]{quotchap}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand\sectfont{\bfseries}
\usepackage{calc,pifont} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcommand*\myheaderfooterfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[ragged]{sidecap}
\usepackage[marginal]{footmisc}
\renewcommand\footnoterule{\vspace*{-3pt}%
    \hrule width 2in height 1.4pt \vspace*{2.6pt}}
\setlength\footnotemargin{10pt}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
}
\usepackage[toc,header]{appendix}
\usepackage{apptools}   

\usepackage{showframe}

%************************************************** added
\usepackage{xstring}

\makeatletter       
    \patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\thechapter}{%
     \IfSubStr{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}{\thechapter}{\appname\,\thechapter}{\chapname\,\thechapter}
    }           
\makeatother    

\newcommand{\appname}{{\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{22pt}{26pt}\selectfont\raisebox{1em}{\textcolor{red}{Appendix}}}} % set the appendix name <<<<<<<<<<<
\newcommand{\chapname}{{\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{22pt}{26pt}\selectfont\raisebox{1em}{\textcolor{red}{\chaptername}}}} % set the chapter name <<<<<<<<<<<
%************************************************** 

\begin{document} 
    \frontmatter
    \chapter*{Ac}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Ac}
    
    \mainmatter
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
    \chapter{Backrre}
    \setcounter{chapter}{14}
    \chapter{Another chapter with \#15}

    \begin{appendices}
        \chapter{Derivation of X}
        The contents...
        \chapter{Derivation of Y}
        Another content...
        \setcounter{chapter}{15}
        \chapter{Derivation of P}
        \setcounter{chapter}{25}
        \chapter{Derivation of Z}
        Another content...      
    \end{appendices}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution works with `xelatex` suppressing the right sidebearing of the chapter number.

For example see [sidebearings and precision left/right alignment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/427068/161015)

[image: a]

[image: b]

[image: c]

[image: d]

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass[11pt,openany,twoside]{book}  

\raggedbottom
\let\cleardoublepage=\clearpage
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\HRule{\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1.5pt}}
\usepackage[dotinlabels]{titletoc}
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{contents={}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hhline}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\usepackage[noindentafter,calcwidth]{titlesec}
\usepackage[courier]{quotchap}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand\sectfont{\bfseries}
\usepackage{calc,pifont} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcommand*\myheaderfooterfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[ragged]{sidecap}
\usepackage[marginal]{footmisc}
\renewcommand\footnoterule{\vspace*{-3pt}%
\hrule width 2in height 1.4pt \vspace*{2.6pt}}
\setlength\footnotemargin{10pt}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
}
\usepackage[toc,header]{appendix}
\usepackage{apptools}   

\usepackage{showframe}

%************************************************** added 
\usepackage{fontspec}% added
\newfontfamily\NCourier[Mapping=tex-text]{Courier New} %
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand\ClipR[1]{% 
    \StrRight{#1}{1}[\tempii]%
    #1\kern-\XeTeXglyphbounds3 \the\XeTeXcharglyph\expandafter`\tempii% 
    }

\renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\NCourier\fontsize{100}{130}\selectfont\color{chaptergrey}}

\makeatletter 
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\thechapter}{%     
\StrRight{\thechapter}{1}[\tempii]
\IfSubStr{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}{\thechapter}{\appname\,\ClipR{\thechapter}}{\chapname\,\ClipR{\thechapter}}
}        
\makeatother  

\newcommand{\appname}{{\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{22pt}{26pt}\selectfont\raisebox{1em}{\textcolor{red}{Appendix}}}} % set the appendix name <<<<<<<<<<<
\newcommand{\chapname}{{\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{phv}\fontsize{22pt}{26pt}\selectfont\raisebox{1em}{\textcolor{red}{\chaptername}}}} % set the chapter name <<<<<<<<<<<
%************************************************** 

\begin{document} 

    \frontmatter
    \chapter*{Ac}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Ac}
    
    \mainmatter
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
    \chapter{ONE}   
    \chapter{TWO}
    \chapter{THREE}
    \chapter{FOUR}
    \chapter{FIVE}
    \chapter{SIX}
    \chapter{SEVEN}
    \chapter{EIGHT}
    \chapter{NINE}
    \chapter{TEN}
    
\begin{appendices}
    \chapter{Derivation of A}   
    \chapter{Derivation of B}   
    \chapter{Derivation of C}
    \chapter{Derivation of D}    
    \chapter{Derivation of E}   
    \chapter{Derivation of F}
    \chapter{Derivation of G}   
    \chapter{Derivation of H}   
    \chapter{Derivation of I}   
    \chapter{Derivation of J}
    \chapter{Derivation of K}   
    \chapter{Derivation of L}   
    \chapter{Derivation of M}   
    \chapter{Derivation of N}
    \chapter{Derivation of O}   
    \chapter{Derivation of P}       
    \chapter{Derivation of Q}   
    \chapter{Derivation of R}
    \chapter{Derivation of S}   
    \chapter{Derivation of T}        
    \chapter{Derivation of U}   
    \chapter{Derivation of V}   
    \chapter{Derivation of W}   
    \chapter{Derivation of X}   
    \chapter{Derivation of Y}   
    \chapter{Derivation of Z}       
\end{appendices}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why are we now renewing the chapter number font? Isn't the command `\usepackage[courier]{quotchap}` enough? Is it possible that we do not renew the chapter number font such that we can set the font type through the quotchap package? Please help.

Comment: @itc Both numbers and letters must be aligned to the right. This is done using xelatex to calculate the correction. `quotchap` needs pdflatex to change fonts, so to do this is not useful. Remember, one question at a time (font family).

Comment: @itc Please add a code example showing the issue on sections names and other font styles used in your document.

Comment: I have modified the code @Simon Dispa

Comment: @itc Use `\newenvironment{myfont1}{\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont}{\par}
\newenvironment{myfont2}{\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont}{\par}`  (and compile with xelatex!)

Comment: @itc `\sfdefault` is set by `\usepackage{helvet}` to `phv`

Comment: @itc  `\normalfont\bfseries\sffamily` is fine. I do not understand your question. In your last example section titles are bold + helvetica.